# How to install php-memcache in xampp ubuntu?

Tags: php, memcached, php-memcached

I have installed xampp for linux from https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html in my `Ubuntu 22.04` OS

After successfully installed, my project is running fine but when I install the php-memchached in my system with the below command but it is not showing in my phpinfo() page.

Command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-memcached
```

Also I tried with the code to check my Memcached Successfully installed or not. But I got the error message that `Class 'Memcached' not found`

Code:

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer("127.0.0.1", 8080);
$response = $memcached->get("sample_key");

if($response==true) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo "Cache is empty";
    $memcached->set("sample_key", "Sample data from cache") ;
}
```

Error Output in Yii console:

```
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

Please let me know how to install the php-memcached in Xappp for my ubuntu system?

Comment: Have you checked php.ini?

Comment: @shingo yes I have checked

Comment: I mean you need add `extension=memcached.so` in the php.ini. And because you install the extension via apt, you need care for the path. If xampp is installed in `/opt/lampp/` you need manually copy `memcached.so` from `/usr/lib/php/<version>/` to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extension/<version>/`.

Comment: Another option is to install extension via PECL `/opt/lampp/bin/pecl install memcached`.

Comment: @shingo thanks for your comment. I missed to add `extension=memcached.so`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php-memcached` extension uses the `libmemcached` library to provide an API for communicating with memcached servers.

So, This extension **requires** [libmemcached client library](https://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html).

The steps. Tried successfully **from a basic ubuntu:22.04 image**:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y net-tools sudo wget nano
```

And xampp install:

```
cd /home
sudo wget https://downloadsapachefriends.global.ssl.fastly.net/8.1.6/xampp-linux-x64-8.1.6-0-installer.run
sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-8.1.6-0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-8.1.6-0-installer.run
```

Then, there are a lot of dependencies to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y memcached
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install php-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
sudo pecl install memcached #note the path to memcached.so
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
add extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/memcached.so #path noted before
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Or another possible install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install memcached #note the path to memcached.so
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
add extension=/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/memcached.so #path noted before
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

With your code:

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer("127.0.0.1", 8080);
$response = $memcached->get("sample_key");

if($response==true) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo "Cache is empty";
    $memcached->set("sample_key", "Sample data from cache") ;
}
```

Results:

```
Cache is empty
```

And phpinfo:
[image]

Reference for more details:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Answer (score 0):

**Steps for installing php-memcached in ubuntu**

first, go to the /opt/lampp/bin/ then run the below command

```
> sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
> sudo pecl install Memcached
```

OR

```
> /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install memcached
```

Once installed then open php.ini(my ini path */opt/lampp/etc/php.ini*) and add the below line in that file

```
extension=memcached.so
```

Finally, restart XAMPP

```
> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```